# problema na validação de formato de arquivo com a gem paperclip 5.1.0, rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4, gem

Model

```
has_attached_file :foto
validates_attachment_content_type :foto, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

Erro no log

```
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/conta/AppData/Local/Temp/66c9eed121277d8be2df09ce25c4687a20171106-5872-1j1pihz.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename foto.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension),content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429 pode ser que esse link te ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Caso deseje desativar o spoofing protection, crie o arquivo:

#### config/initializers/paperclip_media_type_spoof_detector_override.rb

E adicione a ele o código:

```rb
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```